# If two hot resistors are touching each other, will their temperature rise as opposed to not touching?

Tags: resistors, temperature

Consider I have two resistors next to each other both at 165°C. If they were touching each other, would this cause both their temperatures to rise? Or would the temperature stay the same?

Comment: When they touch each other, the surface area on which heat can be dissipated gets smaller, so the remaining surface has to dissipate it and it gets hotter because of that. This even happens when they only **see** each other, because heat transfer works with radiation, too.

Comment: Heat has quality as well as quantity - it ALWAYS moves from higher temperature to lower temperature, regardless of the relative masses. If two bodies are at the same temperature there is no heat flow between them.

Comment: Since you are replacing moveable air (able to leave room for more cool air) with a hot resistor, yes, it is reasonable to assume their temp will rise.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, your argument makes no sense whatsoever. This is basic thermodynamics.

Comment: @Chu - Consider that air surrounding a hot resistor will cool it down, yes? So if you put another hot resistor at the same temperature next to it, then LESS cold air will be exposed to either resistor. It's basic thermodynamics.

Comment: @Chu you misunderstand the question and what is occurring in the situation described. The temperature is an equilibrium between the heat produced in the resistance and that removed by some external cooling mechanism.  Putting them into contact (or possible even close) reduces that cooling.

Comment: @Chu. Yep, basic thermodynamics indeed. Will your temperature rise if instead of placing your left half in cool air, we place it near a stove? I guess so. (For the nitpicking guys: not the internal basal temperature, but the temperature of the epidermis). BTW - the first three comments cover all three type of thermal transfer: radiation, conduction and convection. :-)

Comment: @Chris Stratton, so you have two bodies at the same temperature and you bring them into contact, does their temperature increase, decrease or stay the same?

Comment: @Chu If you bring two bodies at the same temperature into contact, that act does not result in any temperature change. In this question, we must assume that the resistor are surrounded by air and that heat is being added to each resistor at a uniform rate. We assume that because that is the normal operation of a resistor. Given that, moving the resistors closer together will change the heat transfer from the resistors to the air in a way that will make their temperatures rise over time.

Comment: Even if the thermal resistance does not rise one part raises the ambient of the other and therefore both junctions rises with the equivalent of twice the power into the same thermal resistance.  If they were externally heated, then there is no change.

Comment: But it depends on the Rth of touching compared to Rjc of each part. If Rth was much lower then rise cab be doubled ,if much higher rise is much less , such as if the R is an external metal film with ceramic core then interior junction matches external case

Comment: @Chu The origin of your misunderstanding is that you are considering bodies at fixed given temperature T. But the temperature of each resistor is the result of an equilibrium (see Note 1) reached between the heat internally generated by Joule effect and the heat removed by thermal transfer with the surroundings (or in general exchanged with the environment). If you alter the environment around the resistor, you will in general find a different temperature. (Note 1) I am implicitly assuming a stationary situation here (constant average current in the resistors, constant air flow, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the long string of comment debates suggests, bringing the two resistors will cause their temperature to rise.  This will not happen because the resistors are making each other hotter, but rather because you will limit the amount of cooling available.

In both scenarios we assume that the resistors are being cooled by convection.  The resistors are heating the air around them and that is causing the air to rise away.  This may also be forced convection, where we have a fan pushing the air across the resistors.  Regardless of the reason for the air movement, the important fact is that we have air moving past the resistors to cool them.  Anything which decreases this cooling effect will cause the resistors to get warmer.

If you were operating this circuit in a vacuum, the story would be different.  Without air, there would be no convection.  Without the cooling effects of convection, there would be no change in temperature by bringing the two resistors together.

Incidentally, designing circuitry to work in vacuums is very difficult due to heating issues.  Because there is no convection, you have to consciously design your circuit to include direct paths to sink heat way from your chips.  Poorly designed circuits have been known to get hot enough to melt the solder and let the chip fall off of the board.

Comment: SO what is the temperature rise relative to isolated rise "delta T"?

Comment: Bringing them together in vacuum would presumably reduce the cooling by radiation, since in a subset of directions where they "see" one another, there would be no net loss.

Comment: Thanks, just checked the question and see lots of people are having debates about it.

Comment: Also this answers my question because what I was wondering was like if two humans are touching each other heat is preserved, I wondered if it works the same with resistors, turns out not quite, yes they will heat up a little more due to less surface area touching cooler air on both resistors, but will not "increase" heat, like one will not heat up the other by heat conduction, which is what I was really wondering.

Comment: It's mostly similar - both people and resistors convert other forms of energy to heat (something like 100 watts for a person).  But unlike with the resistors, proximity might prompt the humans to either increase or decrease their metabolic rate. Humans are hard to model, their interactions even more so.